# How to I add to this count without it resetting? Is there an easier way to do this?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I am trying to write a bit of code that adds to a count within a function, however when ever the function is called, the count resets. Also if I put the count outside of the function it can't find it.
Is there an easier way of doing this?

```
def testing():

   age = 0

   test = input("grow the person by one year by entering g")
   if test == "g":
       age = age + 1
       testing()
    
testing()
```

Comment: You set your age to zero at the start of the function. You just need to store the value of age globally, outside of the function, or - maybe simpler in your case - give the age variable to the function as argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the "age" variable will be resetted to 0 **every single time the function will be called**.

The reason for that is that you defined the variable inside of the function so the variable can not be saved as you always defined it as 0 at the beginning of the function means, every single time you call the function it starts over with 0.

You have certain ways to solve this, the first one is as you can see from the reply above to define a **global** variable and assign the value 0 to it **outside of the function**!

However you need to be careful with this as you don t aways want to modify global variables as you might loose athe overview in bigger projects and get some bugs.

Here is an other way to create a variable inside of a function but to avoid a global variable modification:

```
def counting():
  age = 0

  while True:

        test = input("grow the person by one year by entering g")
        if test == "g":
            age += 1
            print(age)
        else:
            break

counting()
```

Make sure you understand the difference between local and global variables to understand functions and avoid bugs.
Here you find a link:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the initialization of age out of the method.

You can use it as a global variable, or as a parameter of the method :

**Global variable :**

```
age = 0
def testing():
    global age

   test = input("grow the person by one year by entering g")
   if test == "g":
       age = age + 1
       testing()
    
testing()
```

**Parameter:**

```
def testing(age):

   test = input("grow the person by one year by entering g")
   if test == "g":
       age = testing(age + 1)
   return age

age = 0
testing(age)
```